# Could someone explain when I would use sync -d over sync with no options?

Tags: command, options

I'm looking at an online man page for the sync command and I can't quite figure out the intended use of the `-d` or `--data` option.

Is it faster? Does it have any noticeable effect? Or is it something legacy?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Many filesystems have checksums for meta data. Usual data on the other side is often not checksummed. Using `sync -d` is a faster operation than a complete `sync` and should be preferred in situations where time matters, like hanging on a fail-safe battery. `sync -d` also needs less IO access and thus can increase the lifespan of the device, especially on cheap devices like SDcards and other cheap flash memory technologies.

**Recommend use:**
Use `sync -d` within program loops which are followed with a `sync` at the end of loop and use `sync` or `sync -d; sync` in CLI.

Comment: Who recommends using `sync -d`? There is no reference in the answer.

Comment: I'm the reference and I also explained why it's recommend.